# Webpack bootstrap-loader load custom file after bootstrap

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack to load bootstrap-sass using this plugin [bootstrap-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader)

I've tried to add my custom .scss file and at .bootstraprc i setup like this:

```
bootstrapVersion: 3
styleLoaders:
 - style
 - css
 - sass

appStyles: ./src/sass/main.scss

styles:

# Mixins
mixins: true

# Reset and dependencies
normalize: true
print: true
glyphicons: true

# Core CSS
scaffolding: true
type: true
code: true
grid: true
tables: true
forms: true
buttons: true

# Components
component-animations: true
dropdowns: true
button-groups: true
input-groups: true
navs: true
navbar: true
breadcrumbs: true
pagination: true
pager: true
labels: true
badges: true
jumbotron: true
thumbnails: true
alerts: true
progress-bars: true
media: true
list-group: true
panels: true
wells: true
responsive-embed: true
close: true

# Components w/ JavaScript
modals: true
tooltip: true
popovers: true
carousel: true

# Utility classes
utilities: true
responsive-utilities: true

### Bootstrap scripts
 scripts:
  transition: true
  alert: true
  button: true
  carousel: true
  collapse: true
  dropdown: true
  modal: true
  tooltip: true
  popover: true
  scrollspy: true
  tab: true
  affix: true
```

The problem is when I build the file, my custom css is load before bootstrap file.

My main.scss:

```
@import '~animate.css/animate.min.css';

$color: blue;

body{
   color:$color;
}
```

As i recheck `body{}` is appear after bootstrap. but import file before bootstrap.

Is this suppose to be like this or I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in `.bootstraprc` to add extra styles to the bootstrap.

```
# Import your custom styles here. You have access to all the bootstrap variables. If you require
# your sass files separately, you will not have access to the bootstrap variables, mixins, clases, etc.
# Usually this endpoint-file contains list of @imports of your application styles.
appStyles: ./app/styles/app.scss
```